# Binding element 'stat' implicitly has an 'any' type. TS7031 in Typescript

Tags: typescript

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { report, valueColor } from './Constant'
import StatCard from './StatCard'

export default function ListOfStat() {
  return (
    <div className="w-11/12 mx-auto mt-10 grid gap-2">
      {report.casese.map((stat, index) => {
        const { label, value, delta } = stat
        return (
          <StatCard stat={stat} key={index} valueColor={valueColor[index]} />
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Please Help me out of it! Thanks in advance.
I have done a lot to figure it out. I have copied the code from the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZPrwNK-tz8

The error is

```
Binding element 'stat' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7031

    1 | import React from 'react'
    2 | 
  > 3 | export default function StatCard({ stat, valueColor }) {
      |                                    ^
    4 |   const { label, value, delta } = stat
    5 |   return (
    6 |     <div className="h-28 w-full bg-grey-200 rounded flex items-center p-5 ">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Typescript files (`*.ts` or `*.tsx`) you should declare the types for `StatCard` arguments. Otherwise, rename the files to `*.js` or `*.jsx` if you don't like types.

The fix I suppose for the types should be something like below (please check the correct types):

```js
export default function StatCard({ 
  stat,
  valueColor,
}: { 
  stat: { label: string, value: number, delta: number }
  valueColor: number
}) {
...
}
```